# Filtering a list by a function in Scala

Tags: list, scala, filter

I need to filter a list by the result of a set.
For example this works:

```
(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) filter (_!= 1))
```

Output List(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) 
However I need to filter this list by two function that return a set (for example it returns Set(1,2)) and the current list needs to be filtered by these functions.

Any ideas how this can be done? 
I already tried using the && but it doesn't work

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. What does this mean 'filter this list by two functions that return a set'? Give example of a given input and an expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
scala> val raw = Set(1,2)
raw: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2)

scala> val column = Set(3,4)
column: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(3, 4)

scala> val l = (1 to 9).toList
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> l.filterNot(x => raw(x) || column(x))
res9: List[Int] = List(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Based on @4e6 's comment,

```
scala> l.filterNot(raw ++ column)
res9: List[Int] = List(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: There's no recursion in the code. may be try with dot notation rather than space separated method call. That might confuse the compiler.

Comment: Since `Set[A]` extends function `A => Boolean`, you can do `1 to 9 filterNot (row ++ col)`

Comment: @user2947615 yes, the idea is since `Set` is a function, you can use it as `filter` argument. `++` is just concatenating sets before applying to a function.